# jQuery Add span before and after 2 Set Of Numbers Inside Parent div

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I have no back-end access to this html so JavaScript is my only option.

I tried using the .before() and .after() functions but I can only get it before the first phone umber and after the last one.

Below is what it looks like.

```
<div id="phonenumber">888-888-888 888-888-8888</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<div id="phonenumber">
<span>888-888-888</span> 
<span>888-888-8888</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
$('#phonenumber').html(function(_, html){ //Use html callback function
    return $.map(html.split(/\s+/), function(val){ // split the current text based on spaces and use $.map to get the html span.
        return $('<span/>',{text:val}); //construct the span.
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pc3F5/)**

This is the output:

```
<div id="phonenumber">
      <span>888-888-888</span>
      <span>888-888-8888</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still only adding the span before the first phone number and after the last one.

Comment: Nopes see view source, in the demo.

Comment: show your view source. there must be something else. or just try `html.split(" ")`.